# PyCharm external tool does not seem to invoke the project interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I would like to create an external tool in PyCharm that runs Python interpreter. However, I am not able to enforce the same interpreter as the one used by the project from which I run that external tool.

I will illustrate this on a simplified example.
Let's start with a simple project that will serve as an external tool. I call this project `python-location`. It has a simple `setup.py` with entry point `python-location = python_location.__main__:main`, and `python_location.__main__.py` has this contents:

```py
import os
import sys

def main():
    print(f"PATH 1: {sys.executable}")
    os.system("python -c \"import sys; print(f'PATH 2: {sys.executable}')\"")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I create a virtual env, install the project and execute it by

```sh
python3.9 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install .
python-location
```

I get the correct paths (they both point to the same python 3.9):

```sh
PATH 1: /Users/abc/projects/python-location/venv/bin/python3.9
PATH 2: /Users/abc/projects/python-location/venv/bin/python
```

Then I create another project called `my-app`. I would like to call `python-location` as an external tool with interpreter of `my-app` (so I can later access `my-app` and its dependencies). I prepare a new virtual env in `my-app` directory and call `python-location`:

```sh
python3.9 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install ../python-location/
python-location
```

I get the correct paths again:

```sh
PATH 1: /Users/abc/projects/my-app/venv/bin/python3.9
PATH 2: /Users/abc/projects/my-app/venv/bin/python
```

Now, finally, I would like to call `python-location` as an external tool in PyCharm.
I set `my-app/venv/bin/python` as the project interpreter in PyCharm and create the external tool - see this [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDPbV.png). In case the link does not work, "Program" is `$PyInterpreterDirectory$/python-location` and "Working directory" is `$ProjectFileDir$`.

When I run the `python-location` external tool in `my-app` project window, I get these paths:

```sh
PATH 2: /Users/abc/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
PATH 1: /Users/abc/projects/my-app/venv/bin/python3.9
```

I don't understand why PATH 2 points to a completely different interpreter. I thought `$PyInterpreterDirectory$` should point to the interpreter of the current project. I would like the one from `my-app` venv. Any ideas how can I fix this?

Note that if I change the "Program" of external tool to `$PyInterpreterDirectory$/python` and "Arguments" to `-m python_location`, the result will contain the same problem with PATH 2:

```sh
PATH 2: /Users/abc/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
PATH 1: /Users/abc/projects/my-app/venv/bin/python
```

I am using PyCharm Professional 2020.3.3 on MacOS 11.2.2.